# Prove that $\int_0^\infty J_0(ax) e^{-px}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt {a^2+p^2}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

Prove that

$$\int_0^\infty J_0(ax) e^{-px} dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+p^2}}$$

using power series expansion of Bessel function $J_n(x)$, without using Laplace transform.

**My attempt:**

$$ J_0(ax) = 1-\frac{x^2a^2}{2^2}+\frac{x^4a^4}{2^2 \cdot 4^2}-\cdots$$

Hence

$$\int_0^\infty J_0(ax) e^{-px} dx
=\int^\infty_0 \left\{ 1-\frac{x^2a^2}{2^2}+\frac{x^4a^4}{2^2\cdot 4^2}-\cdots\right\}e^{-px} dx.$$

How to continue from here? I have no idea.

---

*Original image:*
[image]

Comment: Each of those integrals in the expansion is easy to calculate. Look up the Gamma function if need be.

Comment: @lan...yes i got this and i am trying solve but facing difficuty

Comment: What is the difficulty? As it stands the problem seems straightforward.

Comment: @Ian..i will add answer

Comment: @lan....i got this $\sum ^\infty _0 (-1)^r\frac{1}{2^rr!}(\frac{a}{p})^r\frac{1}{p}$

Comment: @lan...from here i don't have any idea to move for further

Comment: That is clearly wrong because a and p do not appear symmetrically. Check your computation of $\int_0^\infty x^k e^{-px} dx$.

Comment: @lan..sorry i made mistake but now i got this $\frac{1}{p}(1-\frac{a^2}{2p^2}+\frac{3a^4}{8p^4}+.....)$

Comment: That looks a little bit more reasonable but it still can't be consistent with the answer you want to get because again $a$ and $p$ do not quite appear symmetrically.

Comment: Funny question, *compute the following Laplace transform without using the Laplace transform* :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, the $a$ parameter is just synctatic sugar, it can be removed through a suitable substitution, so the problem boils down to finding the Laplace transform of $J_0(x)$.
 $J_0(x)$ is an entire function with the following power series:

$$ J_0(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{4^n n!^2} $$
and since for any $p>0$
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{2n}e^{-px}\,dx = \frac{(2n)!}{p^{2n+1}}$$
we formally have:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}J_0(x)e^{-px}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n p^{2n+1}}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{1}{p}\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{-1/2}{n}\frac{1}{p^{2n}} $$
or
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}J_0(x)e^{-px}\,dx = \frac{1}{p\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{p^2}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{p^2+1}}$$
due to the extended binomial theorem.